# $scope.$watch not being fired in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive

```
angular.module('eventsApp')
  .directive('calendar', function(){
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      template: '<div id="eventCal"></div>',
      scope: {
        events: '='
      },
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
        var eventCal = $('#eventCal');
        eventCal.fullCalendar({
          handleWindowResize: true,
          events: scope.events.list
        });

        scope.$watch('events', function(newModel, oldModel){
          console.log(newModel);
          console.log(newModel.list);
          eventCal.fullCalendar('removeEvents');
          eventCal.fullCalendar('addEventSource', newModel.list);
        });

      }
    }
  });
```

with mark up

```
<calendar events="events"></calendar>
```

and with controller

```
angular.module('eventsApp')
  .controller('EventsCtrl', ['$scope', 'calendarService',
    function ($scope, calendarService) {
      $scope.events = {
        list: []
      };

      $scope.$on('configLoaded', function(event, settings){
        calendarService.init(settings);
        calendarService.getEvents($scope.view);
      });

      $scope.$on('eventsLoaded', function(event, events){
        angular.forEach(events, function(value, key){
          $scope.events.list.push(value);
          $scope.$broadcast('eventsReady', $scope.events);
        });
      });

}]);
```

The `scope.$watch` method doesn't seem to be working. The console.logs fire once and show newModel as being empty when fired (accessing its property `list` returns `undefined`) but the object is correctly being referenced because `console.log(newModel)` displays the populated model (i.e. the object is apparently being populated after the watch has already been run). If the object is changing why isn't the watch being called again? Is there another way to check for changes on the scope?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
scope.$watch('events', function(newModel, oldModel){
    console.log(newModel);
    console.log(newModel.list);
    eventCal.fullCalendar('removeEvents');
    eventCal.fullCalendar('addEventSource', newModel.list);
}, true);
```

It's a little inefficient but should work. You need that `true` at end to make the watch recursive. Alternatively you could watch `events.list` directly. In that case `true` wouldn't be needed.

Comment: Thanks @bebraw but that didn't work. The console.log still shows `[]` for `newModel.list` while showing a populated array for list in `newModel`. I've tried listening directly for events.list also.

Comment: Ok, hard to say. Make sure you are using a recent version of Angular. I saw some glitch like this in 1.2 RC. Also, if you have time, set up an online demo (plunkr or so).

Comment: Yeah, I'm using 1.3. I think I'll just add a listener ($scope.$on) in the directive for when the events are loaded. Feels hacky but it works. Is that a terrible idea?

Comment: Given you are using 1.3, you can try `scope.$watchCollection('events.list', ...)`. See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope for a better example. If that doesn't work, I guess `$on` is the way to go.

Comment: I'll look into `$watchCollection`. One more thing, I just used a `$timeout` to check to make sure the object was actually updating correctly and this caused the event listener to correctly fire. I know `$timeout` calls the digest cycle but I'm confused as to why this would affect a watcher. Any thoughts? And thanks for all your help!

Comment: Not sure. You can try a similar thing using `$apply`. Sometimes that's all it takes. Can you set up an online example so it's easier to play around with the problem? See http://plnkr.co/ .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64811/discussion-between-mrberggg-and-bebraw).